# tensorflow callbacks.EarlyStopping not working

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to understand why `tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping` isn't behaving as expected.

In the simple reproducible example below, I'd expect training to stop after validation loss has been consistently decreasing for 3 epochs. You can see that is the case from epoch 5.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import models, layers
import numpy as np

tf.random.set_seed(42)

# make 100 400-dimensional vectors, representing features:
x = np.full((100, 400), 7)
x = np.expand_dims(x, 1)

# make 100 800-dimensional vectors, representing labels:
y = np.full((100, 800), 1)
y = np.expand_dims(y, 1)

model = models.Sequential([
  layers.Input((None,400)),
  layers.Dense(800)
])

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model.summary()

history = model.fit(x=x,
                    y=y,
                    epochs=100,
                    validation_split=0.2,
                    callbacks=tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, patience=3)
                    )
```

Why does the model keeps training until the 100th epoch?

Comment: It's the opposite. The training won't stop unless the training loss has *not* been decreasing for 3 epochs. Also why did you `expand_dims`?

Comment: Nicolas is 100% correct on this. You  may want to write custom callback if you need to alter its behavior - there is a tutorial on TF site.

Comment: @NicolasGervais Thanks for your clarification. I called `expand_dims` to address Tensorflow warnings about incompatible shapes.